# Upgrade Windows 7 without using Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I have Windows 7 installed on my PC and Windows Update doesn't load me upgrades to do, (he searches for endlessly). So I wondered if there is another solution to make updates, perhaps with some third-party tools or software.

Comment: Windows Update Website or several kinds of services that offer to download and do collections. Just search for e.g. `Windows Update Downloader`.

Comment: This should go in the Software Recommendations site. One of the known ones is Simplix which is easy to use and does a great job http://update7.simplix.info/

Comment: @YisroelTech I disagree. There is a microsoft tool specifically for upgrading windows 7 to windows 10 that doesn't involve windows updates. Given that it is changing OS it is suitable for SuperUser and not a software recommendation.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10

Comment: I didn't understand (still not sure) that he is talking about upgrading to Windows 10. I was referring to update Windows 7 with all updates. But in the case of Windows 10, in order to still do the upgrade free he should use this https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/accessibility/windows10upgrade

Comment: Both links will work. Yours is dedicated to upgrading, while mine also comes with options for a new install.

Comment: Your question uses both "update" and "upgrade", which are completely different things.  Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I don't want to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (I explained it badly) but only make system updates without using Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what you want to upgrade windows 7 to, but given that Microsoft had the upgrade to windows 10 in the past, I assume it is windows 10 you want to upgrade to.

Do note that this upgrade was a service that you could do for free, but ended juli 29th 2016 using the GWX tool. This can no longer be done, and as such it is no longer being offered by Windows update.

You can however still download the Windows 10 upgrade tool, and if you have a valid windows 7 license you should be able to upgrade using that tool.

It can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10).

Comment: I was wrong, I just want to do Windows 7 system updates without using Windows Update.

Comment: It is probably better to fix the windows update. There are lots of things you can do if you search for it on the internet.